# Using Hibernate UUIDGenerator via annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, uuid

I'm using my uuid as following:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
private String uuid;
```

but I'm getting a smart Hibernate warning:

> Using
>   org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator
>   which does not generate IETF RFC 4122
>   compliant UUID values; consider using
>   org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator instead

So I want to switch to `org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator`, now my question is how should I tell it to Hibernate's generator. I saw some guy used it as a "hibernate-uuid" - so this is what I've tried, but with negative result:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "hibernate-uuid", strategy = "hibernate-uuid")
@Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
private String uuid;
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

It should be `uuid2`:

```
...
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
...
```

See [5.1.2.2.1. Various additional generators](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e5294).

Comment: [It's the same for 4.1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id). Also, note that it uses java.util.UUID.randomUUID().

Comment: A simple `@Id  @GeneratedValue
    private java.util.UUID id;`
works in Hibernate 5+. See [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers).

Comment: what is the difference between `strategy = "uuid"` and `strategy = "uuid2"` ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé- this should help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218261/hibernate-uuid-hex-vs-uuid2

Comment: @GenericGenerator strategy property is deprecated since hibernate-core 6.2. you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 24):

As @natan pointed out in a comment, if you are using Hibernate 5 the below code is sufficient:

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue
private java.util.UUID id;
```

Define the `id` column with the type of `BINARY(16)` in MySQL or it's equivalent in other SQL implementations.

Comment: or you can also add `@Type(type="uuid-char")` annotation to use `VARCHAR(36)` column

Comment: For postgres @Type(type="pg-uuid") :D

Comment: @senjin.hajrulahovic I am using Hibernate 5.6.15.final. When I try to insert the table with this configuration, throw: cause by: java.sql.sqlexception: field 'id' doesn't have a default value and the execution stops. The DDL that generates me is:

Create table `regions` (
   `ID` Binary (255) Not Null,
   `Name` Varchar (255) not null,
   Primary Key (`ID`)
) Engine = Innodb Default CHARSET = UTF8Collate = UTF8MB4_0900_AI_CI
Everything seems correct in the database, which leads me to believe that Hibernate is not automatically generating the ID field by inserting the data into the table

Answer (score 22):

[HibernateDoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-identifier) says you can use following:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
private String uuid;
```

I hope you are using Hibernate 3.5.

Comment: `system-uuid` is just a name for the Generator, see line 3. In line 2 it is referenced.

Comment: @GenericGenerator strategy property is deprecated since hibernate-core 6.2. you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 11):

Try...

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "uuid", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
public UUID getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(UUID i)
{
    id = i;
}
```

Note the "uuid2" as opposed to "uuid".

Comment: @GenericGenerator strategy property is deprecated since hibernate-core 6.2. you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 5):

This will use UUID v4 and the auto generated uuid will be stored in the column as usual `varchar(36)`:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(length = 36)
private String uuid;
```

This should have some performance impact:

- consumed size is more than `BINARY(16)`
- after hydration the `java.lang.String` instance consumes more memory than `java.util.UUID`: 112 bytes for UUID as string versus 32 bytes (i.e. two longs + obj header) for `UUID`.

But it's much more easier to work with string'ed UUID - easier to write queries and you can see the contents of the table.

Tested on Hibernate 5.3

Comment: @GenericGenerator strategy property is deprecated since hibernate-core 6.2. you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

> Unknown Id.generator: hibernate-uuid

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
@Column(name = "id", unique = true)
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With current 5.4.2 Hibernate version,

if you want a *Human-Readable* **varchar(36)** field in the database table,
but also a *Serializable* **UUID** data type in your Java Class,
you can use `@Type(type = "uuid-char")` **at the same time** you declare your field member with `java.util.UUID` type.

Note that `@Column(length = 36)` is important to reduce from 255 to 36 the field length in MySQL.

Note that with PostgreSQL you should use `@Type(type = "pg-uuid")` instead.

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type
import java.util.UUID
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.Id

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Type(type = "uuid-char") @Column(length = 36)
private UUID id;
```

Comment: this finally worked for me thanks! :) (using UUID in java, varchar(36) in SQL, and spring boot 2.1.1)

Comment: although I've found this generates a uuid even if the given entity already has one from code

Answer (score 0):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name = "UUID_ID")
public String getId(){
return id;
}
```

This is the proper way to use annotation for uuid generators in Hibernate 5.0.11.FINAL.

*Note:* IT is deprecated.