# How to generate 6 char random variable

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I need a unique alphanumeric `code` for my entity.

It is not id. There is also id. But also, this `code` field is unique.

It will be like this

```
"BS" + 6 alphanumeric chars
```

6 alphanumeric.

"BS" is default string. So , all of them will have "BS" in the start

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

I am using spring boot. With hibernate, i can do such things but i  need to make the size 8 or 6+2.

Also my sql has `@Generator` but i could not manage to do

And each time, i dont want to get from db, increment and save. I think this is not good way?

What can i do? A custom `generator`?

I looked for this also

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47934704/10309977

but could not a way to see to do

It will be around 1000 generations. So yearly aroudn 1-10 millions.

Comment: Seems like a good place for a GUID

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams like that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17183247/10309977

Comment: I'd use a full GUID myself. Easy to generate on the client side with an extremely low, nearly non-existant chance of conflict.

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055701/10309977 
i want to use hibernate but it seems i need to write in java too

Comment: No, you don't just want a random string. You want a Guid/UUID. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982748/create-a-guid-in-java

Answer (score 1):

A custom generator implementing the logic you need seems to be the best way to generate your unique alphanumeric `code`.

The "problem" with GUID/UUID is that they have a fixed length (longer than you need), you can still get a sub string but you might have a pattern on how the value is generated.

In my experience, I always have generated unique random code values based on a pattern that can be interpreted and retrieve information from it. This is my approach. You have a 62 chars set to work with 26 lowercase letters 26 uppercase letters and 10 numbers.

If your `code` should end with `"-" +2 numbers` you have to generate the 5 chars string then concatenate your 2 numbers.

Also you might need to make your `code` longer than 8 chars

Comment: But it will be 10000 new object creations per day. So, in a minute maybe 1000. It cant be unique maybe.

Comment: That's why you should consider increasing the number of characters of your `code`, but still if your algorithm of how the `code` is generated is solid and well thought it can be unique. You can calculate how many `codes` you can ideally generate with the set you have.

Comment: How can i check if it exists while saving, with exception?

Comment: You should set the property of unique=true to the code column in your entity. It will throw an exception if the constraint isn't fulfilled

Comment: But i should again try to save that entity if throw exception.