# Strategy to use the same UUID across multiple entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity classes in JPA as below in which **maId** acts as a primary key and foreign key for many other tables.

```
@Table(name = "Table1")
public class Test implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "maId", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String id;
 
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="maId")
    private MFieldData fieldData;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="maId")
    private MPS mps;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="maId")
    private MJob mJob;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="maId")
    private List<MExtension> mlExtensions;

    private Date createdDate;
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;
}
```

Now,this is my another entity.

```
@Table(name = "table 2")
public class Test implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "maId", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String maId;
    private Integer cmd;
    private String routeId;
}
```

By the time I receive a request this is API. I need to Insert the data across multiple tables.

1. How to implement a custom UUID (**maId**) generator and use it in @Id?
2. I need to use the same **maId** which is the unique id for this request across multiple entities while inserting into the DB. I am using a dirty way to do that. But is there any JPA way to solve this problem?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You may be looking for `@MapsId` for #2.

Comment: These are two separate questions. Please make them separate posts.

Comment: One question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6356933/66686

Comment: The other question needs more details about what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The request has to pass the UUID (Called correlation-id) to track.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html can be used.  If you generate in code it may go unknown to caller.  The correlation-id is used to track the request data across systems it may travel due to event publish as well.